# Math Problem Solving

Tags: word-problem

Pokwang delivers newspaper every day. She usually delivers 25 newspapers daily, from Monday through Saturday. Last week, she delivered a total of 178 newspapers. Four of her customers were away from Thursday through Saturday and didn't want newspapers on those days. This week, one customer who usually receives a paper everyday will be away. How many newspapers will she deliver this week?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @DietrichBurde i am confused with the problem pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week she delivered $3*4=12\:$ newspapers fewer than usual and the number was $178$. This week she will deliver $7$ fewer than usual. Can you figure it out now?

Comment: Thanks. So 178 + 12 = 190 (the usual) that means ~32 newspapers daily.  The sentence "She usually delivers 25 newspapers daily" just confuses me.

Comment: @user530299:yes, that statement was there to confuse us. Looks like the average is around $27$ newspapers daily